# How does the placement of the adverbial (before vs after the agent) change the sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction, difference, sentence-meaning

> Both of your examples are grammatical, but what could run you into trouble is when the prepositional phrase only applies to the subject of a passive sentence. For instance:
>
> > [[A]](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/37610/8712) The problem was found by Vasya in the city.
>
> In this sentence, the prepositional phrase is modifying Vasya so that it tells us that Vasya was in the city when the problem was found. This does not necessarily mean that the problem came from the city. (Think, for instance, of the problem as something that could be photographed. Vasya could be anywhere she wants to be when she solves this problem.)
>
> > [B] The problem was found in the city by Vasya.
>
> In this sentence, however, **the problem came from the city** and Vasya was the one to figure it out.
>
> So in some instances, putting the prepositional phrase before the agent can avoid ambiguity.

1. [This](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/37610/8712) still confuses me. I understand [A] to mean that the problem may or may NOT be related to the city (eg an abstract math problem). Vasya might've just found this (math) problem while in the city.

2. Solely based on the sentence alone, and no other context, how can you determine that [B] implies the bolded? Please correct my misinterpretation that [B] simply reorganises [A], with no change in meaning?

Comment: Before anyone answers, I will note that Vasya is a diminutive form of Vassily, a *male* Russian name. (0:

Comment: @CopperKettle Thanks. Is there something about the name that affects my question? I only thought it an arbitrary name from the original question.

Comment: No, whether Vasya is male or female is not important for the question per se.

Comment: @CopperKettle: I think the point is worth making. My natural position is still to assume all names ending in ***-a*** are *female*. After working in Latvia a few times I realized that was a somewhat parochial perspective, but it's hard to change ingrained preconceptions. Personally, I'd be much happier if we always used a couple of standard names familiar to Anglophones - *Jack & Jill*, or *Janet & John* come to mind because they featured in "primer books" for me as a child. Anglophone theoretical physicists often use *Alice & Bob* today, which also seems good to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ["original" explication](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/37610/126) (version **B** implies *the problem **came from** the city*) cited by OP here is slightly misleading. That's a (likely) logical inference, but the only  *syntactic* implication is that the problem was ***found*** in the city. Without further context, it's feasible Vasya was an astrophysicist who discovered a problem with the [Mars Exploration Rover](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opportunity_(rover)) ***while*** in the city.

The referent of *in the city* is ambiguous in **A** (it may modify either *found* or *Vasya*), but in **B** it can only modify *found*. The only way to make it modify *the problem* would be to place it immediately after the intended target noun...

> [C] The **problem in the city** was found by Vasya

---

I could be mistaken here, but I think the reason this meaning can't be imposed on OP's **A** or **B** is there's a general principle that relative clauses such as *in the city* ***<strike>must</strike> should*** apply to the nearest credible preceding candidate term.

But that general principle is affected by whether the relative clause is *adjectival* or *adverbial*. In some contexts (such as OP's) it could be either, and we can "choose" *in advance* which we want - before applying the "nearest credible candidate" rule.

---

There's also the entirely separate issue of whether the relative clause is [*restrictive*](http://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/restrictive_clause.htm) (specifically singling out the Vasya in the city, not other Vasyas elsewhere) or [*non-restrictive*](http://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/non-restrictive_clauses.htm) (just adding information about the "one and only" Vasya). But that seems excessively contrived in OP's context.

---

TL;DR: OP's *"**How** can you determine that [B] implies the bolded [interpretation]?"* is based on the false premise that it's possible to make such an interpretation at all. Syntactically, it's just not possible anyway.

Comment: "… there's a general principle that relative clauses such as *in the city* ***must*** apply to the nearest credible preceding candidate term." <== How is "in the city" a relative clause?

Comment: @F.E.: Terminology isn't my strong suit, so if I've used the wrong term there, perhaps you can tell me what I *should* call it. All I mean is it's a clause that only has meaning *relative to* some nearby text element. And in the case under consideration the issue is *"How do we decide **which** other text element is it associated with?"*.

Comment: I'd probably at first consider "in the city" to usually be a preposition phrase (PP).

Comment: @F.E.: It may well be a PP - but assuming you're only calling it that because it starts with a preposition, I can't see that as particularly useful here. Exactly the same potential ambiguity arises with, say, *lurking in the shadows* (if we allow problems can figuratively *lurk*). I really need a designation that covers most/all such constructions where the "target" may be ambiguous.

Comment: Could you provide a grammar source that uses your naming convention?

Comment: Also, how does your grammar handle the situation when both a PP and a "real" relative clause are dependents within a NP? E.g. *"the problem [in the city] [that none of the king's wise men knew how to solve]"* -- Does your grammar use the term "relative clause" for both dependents?

Comment: @F.E.: +1. Thanks. To confirm, is 'referent' in para 2 the perfect term? Is *in the city*, an [antecedent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antecedent_%28grammar%29)?

Comment: @Upvote Law Area 51 Proposal: I can tell you for sure *in the city* isn't an *antecedent* without having to know anything about grammatical terminology, because in plain English, an *antecedent* means *something that comes **before** something else*. So in your question text, ***Vasya*** is the antecedent of ***she***. You'll have to ask someone who cares more about such things than me (such as F.E.! :) whether it would still be an "antecedent" in something like *"When **she** solved it, **Vasya** felt proud"*. Logically it shouldn't be, but grammar terminology isn't necessarily logical.

Answer (score 0):

Change "problem" to "cat":

```
[A] The cat was found by Vasya in the city.
[B] The cat was found in the city by Vasya.
```

Is it any clearer?  If so, why?

Comment: Even there you'd have to accept that the cat itself may never have been anywhere near the city. Perhaps the cat has always roamed the countryside - but it's got an implanted radio transmitter, and Vasya tracked it down remotely using all kinds of hi-tech equipment in the city.